# How to Hide DropDown Through JavaScript and Show when Some One Select Other dropdown only value 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox, dropdown

//I need to Hide   " meterView" dropdown and when some one select Bypass value //"4" Then Hide meterview Dropdown will show how to do i m really confuse ?

```
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label>State & Action:</label>
                                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="upStateLB" runat="server" CssClass="form-control selectpicker">
                                      <asp:ListItem Text="<<===Status===>>" disabled="true" Value=">" />
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Hybrid</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Bypass</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Rented</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="<<===Action===>>" disabled="true" Value=">" />
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Activate</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Disable</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="meterView" style="display:none" class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label>Meters</label>
                                <div id="meterdropdown" class="input-group col-md-12">
                                    <asp:ListBox ID="DeviceLB" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Select Meters" multiple></asp:ListBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below,

1) Include additional property `ClientIDMode="Static"` in dropdown,

`<asp:DropDownList ID="upStateLB" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>`

2) Add Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#upStateLB').change(function () {
            document.getElementById("meterView").style.display = ($(this).val() == 4) ? "inline" : "none";
        });
    });
</script>
```